# Cloud Firestore Reading an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a an array of alarms (as you'll see below of type Alarm) that I'm trying to store and read from the Cloud Firestore. I'm able to upload the array of alarms but I'm not able to read/decode it. When I use the code below it crashes as I try to decode the alarmArray with the error:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: **"Not a dictionary"**, underlyingError: nil))

SaveData function:

```
static func saveData(alarmArray: [Alarm]) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let firebaseAlarms = try! FirebaseEncoder().encode(alarmArray)

        db.collection(K.FStore.alarmCollection).addDocument(data: [
            K.FStore.userAlarms : firebaseAlarms
        ]) { (error) in
            if let e = error {
                print("Error saving: \(e)")
            } else {
                print("Successfully Saved")
            }
        }
    }
```

LoadData function:

```
    static func loadData() -> [Alarm] {

            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            var alarmArray: [Alarm] = []

            db.collection(K.FStore.alarmCollection).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in    
                if let e = error {
                    print("error retrieving from Firestore, \(e)")
                } else {
                    if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents {
                        for firebaseAlarms in snapshotDocuments {
                            alarmArray = try! FirebaseDecoder().decode(Alarm.self, from: firebaseAlarms) //the app crashes here!
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        return alarmArray
    }
```

Alarm model:

```
struct Alarm: Codable {
    var uuid: String
    var time: Time
    var label: String
    var repeatStatus: [DetailInfo.DaysOfWeek]
    var isOn: Bool
    var onSnooze: Bool
}
```

I'm using the CodableFirebase pod's documentation [here](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase) and Firebase's documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0), but struggling to put them together.

Answer (score 0):

Please declare your model's all property as optional.

Also property name should be same as firebase.

if you need different name use coding keys.

Serialize your firebase data before decoding.

Put your decoding line on do catch block.

Also do not use firebase decoder use Swift decoder to decode the data.

```
guard let JSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted) else { return }

guard let alarm = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Alarm.self, from: JSONData) else { return }
```

If the error shows again use manual mapping.

Comment: Those are very general suggestions and they're not relevant to this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by changing the loadData() function to this:

```
static func loadData() -> [Alarm] {


    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var alarmArray: [Alarm] = []
    db.collection(K.FStore.alarmCollection).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in

        if let e = error {
            print("error retrieving from Firestore, \(e)")
        } else {
            if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents {
                for doc in snapshotDocuments {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    if let alarm = data[K.FStore.userAlarms] {
                        alarmArray = try! FirebaseDecoder().decode([Alarm].self, from: alarm)
                        print(alarmArray)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return alarmArray
}
```